# Creating a deck of cards by adding a card each time a user inputs a value

Tags: java

I am trying to make a deck of cards by a user input. E.g. if the user entered 0,4 the card shown would be stored as the 4 of hearts. The code I have so far is not working at all for the suits. I plan to do the same else if for the card values as well.

```
public void addCard() {
    String suit[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
    String value[] = {"ZZZZ", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    System.out.println("Please enter a suit");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int card[] = card.nextLine();

    int i;

    if(int card[] = 0) {    
        String newSuit [] = String suit[0];
    } else if(int card[] = 1){
        String newSuit [] = String suit[1];
    } else if (int card[] = 2){
        String newSuit [] = String suit [2];
    } else if (int card[] = 3){
        String newSuit [] = String suit [3];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive - what's not working exactly? (Besides the fact that your code won't compile as it's currently written...)

Comment: Totally unclear, as to what is going on and what exactly are your expecting.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942050/deck-of-cards-java

Comment: It certainly gives you a compiler error, which you didn't mention at all. Why?

Comment: Creating a deck of cards by adding a card each time a user inputs a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably get a compiler error in this (and the next ones) line:

```
if(int card[] = 0)
```

`int card[]` is an array, which is eventually an `Object`, and you are trying to assign to it a primitive value... which won't work.
Besides, it looks like you are trying to compare something, which rather uses `==`, and not `=`.