# Most efficient way to build a deck of cards (ArrayLists, Arrays, etc.)?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I am new to Java and Started using ArrayLists before arrays. 
I like that they are more similar to Python lists, and understand that ArrayLists contain only objects rather than primitives, which in my mind, makes them more useful for lists containing multiple types.
I wrote this to show how I'd make a deck of cards (everything is static just for this example):

```
public class Deck {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Random newRan = new Random();

    private static final List RANKS = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
            10, "jack", "queen", "king"));
    private static final List SUITS = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("hearts", "diamonds", "clubs",
            "spades"));

    private static List makeDeck() {
        List result = new ArrayList();
        for (Object i : SUITS) {
            for (Object j : RANKS) {
                result.add(Arrays.asList(i, j));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List deck = makeDeck();

        for (Object i : deck) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this may slow down the program, as I have read elsewhere, but I was wondering what would be a better, more conventional or clean way of accomplishing this?
All constructive criticism welcomed.

(Again, I'd like to say that I wrote this little code just to demonstrate my question about arrays and arrayLists and their functionality, a quick example.)

Comment: Since your values are never going to change, you could just create enums for suit and rank.

Comment: Both RANKS and SUITS should be [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: See other related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942050/deck-of-cards-java

Comment: You should forget efficiency for now. Your code is poor quality-wise, and measuring the speed of something small like that is useless. You can worry about speed when you've written something that actually takes a measurable amount of time. Also find some decent tutorials, you'll want to use generics most likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)!

Enums are great for things like Card Suits and Ranks. Much better than collections of Strings, actually. For example...

```
enum Suit {
    HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS;
}
```

Enums can have their own properties like any other class, too, but that's something that you can read up on separately. The tall-and-short of Enums is that they are singletons in runtime and each is intrinsically unique by definition. These are very handy properties.

Next, I advise that you implement a formal `Card` class. A Card is more than a list of properties. You'd want something like this as a base for your Card class:

```
class Card {
   private final Suit suit;
   private final Rank rank;

   public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
       this.suit = suit;
       this.rank = rank;
   }

   public Suit getSuit() { return this.suit; }

   public Rank getRank() { return this.rank; }
}
```

Users of your code will thank you for this, versus remembering whether a list's first element is the suit or the rank of the card.

You'd have to refactor your `makeDeck` method to use these new enums and classes, but the general approach would remain the same. Iterate over all the Suits and, in that iteration, iterate over all the ranks and create a new Card instance for each iteration. That way, you're making a new Card with each value of Rank and Suit. You'd end up with a full deck.

Now, the question you want to ask yourself is this: Is a Deck merely a List of Cards, or does it merit its own class? There is no right or wrong answer; it's up to you and what your program needs. Maybe just using a List of Cards is perfectly fine.

Oh, and on that note (and maybe this is just a bit of a nit-pic), if you want a "List of Cards", make it a List of Cards. `List<Card>` is better than just `List`. Generic types are your friend!

Comment: Ahh great, thanks. I was never really sure what enums were, but I'll definitely read up on them. Thought Arrays and ArrayLists were some of my only options.

Comment: I'll be trying this asap. Would it be useful for a Card object to include possible scores?

Comment: @ColeDooley I would save card-scoring for something different. By this I assume that you are talking about "kickers" in poker, or the like, where one card is intrinsically "Greater" than another. Having a separate helper class to determine such things would be a better approach IMHO.

Comment: @ColeDooley An enum can contain its own fields, so yes. The `Suit` enum can have for example a `name` field (hearts, diamonds...) and a `symbol` field containing ♠, ♦ and so on. Likewise for `Rank` you could have a name of the rank and a numerical value, or whatever you fancy.

Comment: @ColeDooley biziclop brings up a good point. I wrote my own Card class recently for a pet project, and I would advise you to give your enums their own private properties and constructors where you specify things like "human readable name" and "symbol". Enums--similar to classes--can also have their own public methods (e.g. `getHumanReadableName`) which you might find useful. The link I posted  on Enums at the top covers all of this. A very good read!

Answer (score 0):

First, remove these lines

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Random newRan = new Random();
```

Since they aren't used anywhere.

Second, use more object-oriented approach (**you** tagged it oop):

```
enum Suite {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES};
enum Value {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING};
class Card
{
    public Suite suite;
    public Value value;
    public Card (Suite s, Value v) {
        suite = s;
        value = v;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return s + " :: " + v;
}
```

And generics:

`List` -> `List<Card>`
`ArrayList` -> `ArrayList<Card>`

And your creation method can be written as following:

```
for (Suite s : Suite.values ())
    for (Value v : Value.values ())
        result.add (new Card (s, v));
```

This program should look like:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {
    public static enum Suite {
        DIAMONDS,
        SPADES,
        HEARTS
    }

    public static enum Value {
        ACE,
        TWO,
        THREE,
        FOUR,
        FIVE,
        SIX,
        TEN,
        JACK,
        QUEEN,
        KING
    }

    public static class Card {
        public Suite suite;
        public Value value;

        public Card (Suite s, Value v) {
            suite = s;
            value = v;
        }

        public String toString () {
            return String.format ("%s: %s", suite, value);
        }
    }

    private static List<Card> makeDeck() {
        List<Card> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Suite s : Suite.values ())
            for (Value v : Value.values ())
                result.add (new Card (s, v));
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Card> deck = makeDeck();

        for (Card i : deck) {
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finished - please re-rate

Comment: Similar to my answer, but with inner classes. Personally I believe it better practice avoiding those unless they're helper classes, like custom exceptions or something, but whatever. +1 for providing the card's toString and a printout of the deck. Although since you know how big the deck's going to be, you should specify the ArrayList's starting size.

Comment: @PerryMonschau Specifying the `ArrayList`'s initial size is not as great performance boost as  you may think.

Comment: Would you care to backup that claim?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start off by pointing out that arrays are not limited to exclusively holding primitives.  Arrays can hold objects as well.  For example..

```
vehicle[] cars = new vehicle[10];  // creates an array of 10 vehicle objects
```

Now that that is out of the way, the main difference between an array and an array list is that arrays are fixed in size, where as array lists are not.  Array lists are actually just regular arrays at the core, but when the JVM notices an array list is approaching it's capacity limit, it simply copies over the array contents to a bigger array all behind the scenes.  This gives the effect that the array can grow in size as needed when using an array list.

The side-effect of this is that there is some additional over head in the processing, but very minimal and processing that you would need to do yourself if you were to create an array that wasn't big enough.  This processing is pretty much negligible but because your arrays are going to be a fixed length, an array list isn't going to do much for you.

So in short, if you aren't sure how much space your array will need, an array list is the easiest way to go.  But if your arrays will be fixed in length (as yours will be), then a plain ol' array is all you need.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Note, each of the following should be in separate files:

```
public class Card {
    SUIT suit;
    RANK rank;
    public Card(SUIT suit, RANK rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
}

public enum SUIT {
    Diamonds,
    etc
}

public enum RANK {
    Ace,
    Two,
    etc
}

public class Deck {
    ArrayList<Card> cards;

    public Deck() {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>(RANK.values().length*SUIT.values().length); //for efficiency, specifies how big the arraylist should start as
        for(SUIT s : SUIT.values())
            for(RANK r : RANK.values())
                cards.add(new Card(s,r));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck(); //much cleaner code in main
    }
}
```

Comment: This code wouldn't compile if you tried it. Enums must be separated by commas, and `2` is a reserved keyword. You would need to use something like `TWO`.